# what is the importance of using key value pairs in mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am beginner to mapreduce. Everywhere I see it only states that mapreduce uses key-value pairs. But I don't find clear reason behind using key-value pairs.

Thanks is advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadoop is mainly used to do data Analysis. In data Analysis we look at statistical and/or logical techniques to describe and illustrate, condense and recap, and evaluate data. We by no means modify the data.

Hadoop deals with structured, unstructured and semi-structured data. Schema is not static unlike RDBMS. If, We were to have static schema we can directly work on columns instead of keys and values.

Keys and values are not the intrinsic properties of the data, but they are chosen by the person analyzing the data. So, to do any analysis we have to specify what we are looking for( Key ) and what's it's worth( value ).

Answer (score 1):

Key value would be useful say where you have group by clause with multiple employees in a department and you want to find how many employees are there in each department, then department id would be key and employee count say as value.

Lets say you want to find maximum of numbers in the file and say file is

```
file1.txt
1 
2
3
file2.txt
4
5
6
```

Now mapper is going to read say file1.txt and will read line by line in key value pair as 
    1 (key as line number) 1 (value)
    2 (key as line number) 2 (value)
    3 (key as line number) 3 (value)

And say produces just one output (say includes combiner) as:

```
file1 as key 3 as value
```

Output from other mapper would be

```
file2 as key 6 as value
```

And then reducer will take that input as key value as

```
file1 3
file2 6
```

And will produce final key value pair as say:

```
MAX 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a simple example of word count example.
In word count program mapper receives simple offset as a key and entire line as a value.
We split the line into words and write (word,1) as output of mapper.Now reducer will receive the word as a input key and iterable value object which we traverse and get total count for that word. Before reducer receives the input hadoop does shuffling and sorting because of which you get the input to reducer in sorted order and because of that reducer gets the  output of all the mappers for the same key  into combined format. Now if we don't produce everything into the key and value format we will not be able to combine all the records from all the mapper for giving it to the single reducer.